# 'str' does not support the buffer interface - Python 3

Tags: sockets, python-3.x

```
import socket

serverName = "hostname"
serverPort = 12000

clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
message = input('input lowercase sentence:')
clientSocket.sendto(message, (serverName, serverPort))
modifiedMessage, serverAddress = clientSocket.recvfrom(2048)
print (modifiedMessage)
clientSocket.close()
```

gives this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/server1.py", line 11, in <module>
    clientSocket.sendto(message, (serverName, serverPort))
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

What do I do?

---

I've encode this code

```
import socket

serverName = "hostname"
serverPort = 12000

clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)


message = input('input lowercase sentence:').encode('ascii')

clientSocket.sendto(message,(serverName, serverPort))

modifiedMessage, serverAddress = clientSocket.recvfrom(2048)


print (modifiedMessage.decode('ascii'))

clientSocket.close()
```

But it still error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "J:\Sistem Jaringan\Task I\client.py", line 11, in <module>
    clientSocket.sendto(message,(serverName, serverPort))
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Sockets sent bytes to the other end of the connection.  Encode strings to bytes before trying to send.  In the sendto method, change `message` to `message.encode()`.  Add argument `encoding='xyz'` if you do not want the default utf-8 encoding.  The `modifiedMessage` you receive will also be bytes, and you may want to decode it to a string.

Comment: Can you give me the full correct code?

Comment: I answered your 'buffer interface' question. Please acknowledge that by accepting it.  As to your new question, hostname is the name of the argument, but 'hostname' is not a recognized hostname.  I believe 'localhost' is.  With that, you get another error.  In order for the client to connect to a server, there must be a server.  You need to also write a server.py that starts a 'localhost' server listening on the server port. This has to be run first.  The socket doc should have an example.